# "Sätze und satzwertige Infinitivphrasen können Gegenstand von Ausklammerung ins Nachfeld sein."-English translation

Tags: translation, word-order

Here is a sentence taken from Die Grammatik von Duden:

> Sätze und satzwertige Infinitivphrasen können Gegenstand von Ausklammerung ins Nachfeld sein.

I cannot quite make sense of the English translation of the given sentence. Is it like

> Sentences and sentence-worthy infinitive phrases can be subjects of exclusion in the Nachfeld.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A translation request should identify a specific problem, see https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/q/628/. You say you cannot make sense of the English translation; can you make sense of the original?

Comment: @DavidVogt: How any more "specific" than a certain sentence and its translation could it possibly be, hm?

Comment: Specific would mean identifying a phrase or word or structure that causes the problem, but also telling us what you do already understand. All explained in the linked post.

Answer (score 1):

You rightly complain concerning the awful style.

Referring [Wikipedia: Feldermodell](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feldermodell_des_deutschen_Satzes) I see, that *Ausklammerung* is moving from within the *Satzklammer*/*Mittelfeld* towards the *Nachfeld*. (Note, that *ins* translates to *towards*, not to *in*.)

A simpler translation would be

> Sentences and sentence-worthy structures may be moved into the *Nachfeld*.

Answer (score 0):

"Sentence-worthy" strikes me as odd, I would propose:

*Infinitival clauses may undergo extraposition to the Nachfeld*, (or: *may undergo rightward shift into the Nachfeld.*)

"Satzwertiger Infinitiv" is a term from a traditional analysis which maintained that all "clauses" (or sentences), including subordinate clauses, had to contain a finite verb. Therefore, an infinitival construction could not be called a clause. Instead, such infinitivals were dubbed not "Satz" but "satz-wertig" = roughly: "clause-equivalent". This view is outdated, but the term has remained. I would simply call it "infiniter Nebensatz".